# Is there any way to replace (input) zeros with a function of (1/2)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace the value of 0 with .5, or 1/2 when it has been input initially.

For example, I am trying to have it done before the functions are added. I need to redefine the value of 0 for the input only, and only for the single instance of 0 itself. Not values of 10+.

Here is the project information:

```
IN = input("Enter IN: ")
N = input("Enter N: ")
NP = input("Enter NP: ")

### These two lines are the part I can't get to work:
if digit == float(0):
    digit = float(.5)
###

init = (float(IN)*(float(1)/float(2)))
baselimiter = - (float(N)*(float(1)/float(2))) + ((float(IN)* 
(float(1)/float(2))) * (float(NP)*(float(1)/float(2))))
lset = init + baselimiter
limitconverto1 = (lset / init) * (init / lset)
infalatetoinput = (((init * float(IN))) / init )
limit = limitconverto1 * infalatetoinput

result = limit

print(result)
```

Comment: what is `digit`?

Comment: where is the digit?

Comment: The digit would be IN, N, or NP.

IE:

IN = 0
N = 5
NP = 25

Trying to get the 0 to = 1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a code that does what you want.

Now to be honest, it works but I don't understand WHY you do that. You do a bunch of weird calculations like multiplying and dividing by the same number...

```
IN = float(input("Enter IN: "))
N = float(input("Enter N: "))
NP = float(input("Enter NP: "))

# The part that interests you. 
IN = 0.5 if IN == 0 else IN
N = 0.5 if N == 0 else N
NP = 0.5 if NP == 0 else NP

init = IN * 1/2 
baselimiter = -N*1/2 + IN*1/2*NP*1/2 # Removed all the superfluous float() and parenthesis.

lset = init + baselimiter
limitconverto1 = (lset / init) * (init / lset) # That's just always 1. What is intended here?
infalatetoinput = (((init * float(IN))) / init ) # That's always IN. Same question?
limit = limitconverto1 * infalatetoinput # Equivalent to 1 x IN...

result = limit

print(result) # Your result is always IN...
```

Comment: Thanks. The other stuff is all fine. It is done with a purpose. The function itself is part of a modular format I am writing for wave representations, limitation, rectification, and feedback systems.

Comment: Thanks. The other stuff is all fine. It is done with a purpose. The function itself is part of a modular format I am writing for wave representations, limitation, rectification, and feedback systems.

Comment: Ok no problem. Then in general you can remove many parenthesis and it's fine to multiply different types of number (float x integer = float) without using `float()` on every term. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one-liners when you declare the variables:

```
IN = (float(input("...")) if float(input("...")) != 0 else .5)
```

One-liners are `for` loops or `if` statements (or both) that are in one line instead of multiple lines when declaring variables. They can only be used for the declaration of variables. The one-liner I suggested is would be in multiple lines:

```
if float(input("...")) != 0:
    IN = float(input("..."))
else:
    IN = .5 #You don't need to say float(.5) since .5 is a float anyway.
```

More about One-Liners: [One-Liners - Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Powerful%20Python%20One-Liners)

I hope this edit of my previous answer fully answers your question, for more clarification I will be available on the comments

Comment: Hey, thanks.

This is my first project, so I am unsure what you meant. Could you clarify? Is there a way to ensure if 0 gets entered it is replaced with .5 for any of the 3 inputs? I do need to make sure the inputs are always floats (as decimals will be needed too), but it sounds like you are saying that can be simplified. There's an easier way to do that?

Comment: If you want the digits to be float without exception, you need to specify that when the variables are defined: `IN = float(input(“...”)` . I also just realised that the piece of code  I suggested doesn’t solve your problem. My apologies, I will look for a way to fulfill your request and suggest another piece of code ASAP.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, feel free to mark it accepted so we know if you want more clarification or if everything is OK